# sql stored procedure set * result to parameter

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this sql statement :

```
select * from table where id=1
```

I want to use stored procedure to stored it, i made it like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.table
    (
    @ID int,
    @data   OUTPUT
    )
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    SELECT * FROM Offer WHERE ID = @ID
    END
```

#### question

how to set the output of the stored procedure to the `data` parameter?

thanks

#### Edit

I am calling that stored procedure from JDBC.

Comment: You don't need a output parameter to return a resultset from a stored procedure. The select statement you have is enough.

Comment: i am using that storedprocedure from jdbc, that is why i need out put, right?

Comment: I don't know how to consume a recordset in JDBC but I know it is not with an output parameter. I would guess you should use something like executequery and pass the stores procedure name as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.table
    (
    @ID int
    )
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    SELECT * FROM Offer WHERE ID = @ID
    END
```

To return all columns you don't need OUTPUT parameter you can simply use stored procedure like above.